# What am i doing wrong in my relationship between tables?

Tags: java, mysql

Im trying to create a new user through a form and it worked for half an hour and now it stopped working. Im creating an user which has a dni field which is a fk from the table medicos.

This is my table for users

```
create table Usuarios
(
ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
NOMBRE_USUARIO VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
CONTRASENA VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
estado boolean,
TIPO_USUARIO INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (TIPO_USUARIO) REFERENCES TiposUsuario(ID),
dni varchar(11) NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (dni) REFERENCES Medicos(DNI)
);
```

This is my table Medicos:

```
create table Medicos
(
dni VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
nombre VARCHAR(25),
apellido VARCHAR(25),
sexo VARCHAR(25) ,
nacionalidad VARCHAR(25),
fechaNac DATE,
direccion VARCHAR(50),
localidad VARCHAR(50),
provincia VARCHAR(50),
telefono VARCHAR(25),
celular VARCHAR(25),
correo VARCHAR(25),
estado INT,
id_especialidad INT,
FOREIGN KEY(id_especialidad) REFERENCES Especialidades(ID)
);
```

Now on my form im setting the dni as the following in my method in my controller:

```
u.setDni(request.getParameter("txtDni"))
```

And when i submit my form i have the following error message

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bdturnos`.`usuarios`, CONSTRAINT `usuarios_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`dni`) REFERENCES `medicos` (`dni`))
```

Why is it this? I know this kind of error is due to a mistake that im doing while making the relationship with tables but i cannot identifying which is the mistake.

Comment: I think more info is required. I'd assume the issue is that the medicos record is not present when attempting to add usarios but are you intending to create both in the same form submission, or do you expect the medicos record to be there already? The data model is clear but we'd need to know more about what your code is doing and how it is inserting data

Comment: We need more information: What content do you have int the database? What is the SQL statement you are executing?